Overflow ERROR in flutter_quill toolbar menus
The default button menus of QuillSimpleToolbar appear below the keyboard. This is strange since it didn't happen in previous versions.
return Column(
  children: [
    QuillEditorWidget(
      padding: padding,
      newNote: newNote,
      quillController: _quillController,
    ),
    QuillSimpleToolbar(
      configurations: QuillSimpleToolbarConfigurations(
        controller: _quillController,
        toolbarSectionSpacing: 10.0,
      ),
    ),


  ],
);

enter image description here
enter image description here
In previous versions, I used the QuillToolbar widget, which lost some parameters, and I didn't understand its new logic very well. So, I tried to find other options like QuillToolbar.simple, but I also missed some parameters until I managed to find QuillSimpleToolbar, which had the same parameters. I only had to copy and paste my code. Then I encountered the mentioned error, which I'm sure also happened with the previous widgets. I tried various ways but couldn't achieve anything. I wonder... maybe flutter_quill implemented some parameter to overlay the internal menus of the toolbar, and I can't find it...
Some more changes: Due to updates, flutter_quill removed the QuillProvider widget, which might have something to do with it or not... in this case, I have removed it and only left a column with the editor and the toolbar.
before:
return QuillProvider(
  configurations: QuillConfigurations(
    controller: _quillController,
    sharedConfigurations: QuillSharedConfigurations(
      locale: Locale(S.current.code_locate),
    ),
  ),
  child: Column(
    children: [
      QuillEditorWidget(
        padding: padding,
        newNote: newNote,
        quillController: _quillController,
      ),
      QuillToolbarWidget(
        scrollController: scrollController,
        quillController: _quillController,
        noteId: noteId,
        newNote: newNote,
      ),
    ],
  ),
);

now:
return Column(
  children: [
    QuillEditorWidget(
      padding: padding,
      newNote: newNote,
      quillController: _quillController,
    ),
    QuillSimpleToolbar(
      configurations: QuillSimpleToolbarConfigurations(
        controller: _quillController,
        toolbarSectionSpacing: 10.0,
      ),
    ),


  ],
);

These are some of the changes I made in the new version of flutter_quill.
packages:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill
